# unaligned to 32 bits write exception in cpp/embedded

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, embedded, pragma

I have the following union:

```
union {
    volatile  uint32_t  reg;

    struct {
        volatile  uint32_t  Var1 : 1;
        uint32_t : 3;
        volatile  uint32_t  Var2 : 4;
        volatile  uint32_t  Var3 : 8;
        volatile  uint32_t  Var4 : 8;
    } bit;
}unionA;
```

and I have cpp file which I **can not change** (I can change the h or the union).
the cpp calls to a `_register.unionA.bit.Var4`.

within the assembly I see it tries to write to offset 16 (bits).

the CPU gives me an exception.

The processor is Xtensa.
The code is not mine but i need to merge it with my code.
Can NOT change the .c/cpp only the .h

The compiler tranalates it to S8I (store of 8 bits)
I would like to disable this option here and use S32I.

Is there any attribute/pargma/something else that I can place within compiler flags/h files so it will always write 32 bits and not the 8 bits with offset of 16

Comment: attributes and pragmas are compiler and often target specific rather then language specific.  You should specify the compiler and target in use, *and* the command line or compiler/linker options in use.  If you are using a compiler that supports multiple variants of an architecture such as ARM, then you need to make sure your target settings match the target to ensure that the compiler will generate code that is compatible with your processor's instruction set and bus architecture.  Different variants often have differing alignment requirements.

Comment: What is your processor, compiler, the command line that compiled the .c file you are having problem and the command line you used to call the linker.

Comment: Nice, a near perfect example of code you should never ever use.  I use code like this in interviews to see if the candidate can explain what is wrong, bonus if they can explain multiple things wrong.

Comment: Would still be bad but significantly less of a problem if you could #define _register.unionA.bit.Var4  ((volatile unsigned char *)(0x12345)  but C and C++ dont like that.

Comment: The solution is to toss out the non-portable, non-deterministic bit-field crap ASAP and then use bit-wise operators instead.

Comment: Hi all
The processor is Xtensa.
The code is not mine but i need to merge it with my code.
Can NOT change the .c/cpp only the .h

The compiler tranalates it to S8I (store of 8 bits)
I would like to disable this option here and use S32I.

Thanks